# How to tell if I am inside a Vagrant host?

Tags: vagrant, environment

Whats a bulletproof way to determine if I am running inside a vagrant machine?

Guest OS is Debian Linux, though if there are indicators per-os that would be great to have documented as well.

Comment: What do you mean a "vagrant machine"? Just any vm that was started via vagrant? I doubt there is a way, b/c even if there was evidence of vagrant on the disk maybe it has since been packaged and is run via virtual box now.

Comment: let "vagrant machine" refer to any virtual machine that was created by vagrant as the result of an initial `vagrant up` command.

Answer (score 5):

AFAIK, there isn't a way outside of your own customizations. One idea that comes to mind is to touch a file that you then reference from your apps. Add something like `config.vm.provision "shell", inline: "touch /etc/is_vagrant_vm"` to the bottom of your Vagrantfile and base your conditionals around the existence of that file.

Comment: @ThorSummoner I wanted to add this as an answer for anybody else who winds up here, until somebody smarter waltzes through :)

Comment: Yeah I was thinking about setting an environment variable for myself, but I was just hoping that soemthing would preexist to use.

Answer (score 5):

Provisioning a file that you can check the existence of seems like the most reliable way to handle this.

Another option if you don't want to write files to the box would be to check for the existence of the `vagrant` user itself:

```
grep -q '^vagrant:' /etc/passwd && echo 'Vagrant environment: true'
```

This is not foolproof as others have indicated, and it is possible (although uncommon) to have a vagrant box that uses a different user to connect as.

Checking the user's existence also would not work reliably if you have machines in your environment with a user account called vagrant that are not *actually* vagrant boxes, but that would also be fairly uncommon.

Comment: Checking the user name is probably pretty reliable, that or checking for the /vagrant folder. These aren't guaranteed to exist, but they have on every vagrant machine I've worked with to day. (which is just the stock Ubuntu ones)

Comment: There is no vagrant user on the 16.04 LTS version. There is a `/vagrant` directory though.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there is any bulletproof way for this, but one thing I often do is to config my vagrant environment's shell UI to be different from the shell UI of my host machine. This way I can tell the difference at first glance.  It also helps if you want to distinguish among multiple vagrant environments.

To customize the shell UI, [oh-my-zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh) will come in handy.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't run a vagrant instance in your vagrant instance:

```
if which vagrant > /dev/null 2>&1; then
    echo "This is most likely the host"
fi
```

Comment: You could get more clever with "vagrant status" if you do have vagrant installed in the guest OS.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `facter`

```
facter | grep vagrant
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I was able to answer the question with a very small chunk of bash. The `-e` flag checks if the file exists. Change `provision` to a file path that makes sense for your build.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

user=$USER

provision=/vagrant/Vagrantfile
if [ -e $provision ]
then
  echo "Vagrantfile found..."
  echo "Setting $user to vagrant..."
  user=vagrant
fi

# Example usage
cd /home/$user
```

*Tested on "centos/7"*

Answer (score 0):

In vagrant your are in control of which IP you are running against, so you could change it to for example 192.168.0.10

Then:

```
curl localhost:8080/health => in local e.g spring-boot

curl 192.168.0.10:8080/health => in vagrant
```

NOTE: /health assumes spring-boot but you could also use your own implementation of a /health endpoint as well